# RecyclerView doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I make an app which use API and should show some basic data (exchange rates) on the screen.
But elements of `recyclerView` doesn't appear on the screen. I can see only textview.
Trying to find a problem for a days, can't do anything..

[image: screen]

Here's some code:

StartFragment:

```
class StartFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentStartBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: StartAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[StartViewModel::class.java]
        recyclerView = binding.rvStart
        adapter = StartAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        viewModel.getCash()
        viewModel.myCashList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { list ->
            list.body()?.let { adapter.setList(it) }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

StartAdapter:

```
class StartAdapter:RecyclerView.Adapter<StartAdapter.StartViewHolder>() {

    private var listStart = emptyList<CashItem>()

    class StartViewHolder(val binding: ItemMoneyLayoutBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): StartViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemMoneyLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return StartViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listStart.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: StartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.itemName.text = listStart[position].ccy
        holder.binding.itemBuy.text = listStart[position].buy
        holder.binding.itemSale.text = listStart[position].sale
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun setList(list: List<CashItem>){
        listStart = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

fragment_start.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.start.StartFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Repository:

```
class Repository {

    suspend fun getCashMoney(): Response<Cash>{
        return RetrofitInstance.api.getCash()
    }

    suspend fun getNonCashMoney(): Response<NonCash>{
        return RetrofitInstance.api.getNonCash()
    }
}
```

Simply tried to delete textview "Start" cause it could block the rv.
Any other attempts to change code failed. I guess using viewBinding can be an issue, but I can't find where exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of LayoutManager.

Just like this:

```kotlin
recycleView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
```